# How to return data in POST request (django/tastypie)

Tags: django, tastypie

How do I customise and place data in the response to a POST request?
At first I thought I should place my code in `obj_create` but it looks like `create_response` is the place I should place my code.

My resource looks like this:

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

    def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
        super(TestResource, self).create_response(request, data, response_class, **response_kwargs)
```

However I get a `HTTP/1.0 204 NO CONTENT` error; when I remove the `create_response` function, it works as normal. Shouldn't calling super on the function I'm overriding have no effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must **return** response.

```
def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
    return super(TestResource, self).create_response(request, data, response_class, **response_kwargs)
```

But I would use `dehydrate` method for that:

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.request.method == 'POST':
            bundle.data['my_custom_data'] = 'my_data'

        return bundle
```